# Is it possible to get more precise reverse geocoding?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, geocoding

I've found some methods of reverse geocoding work better than others, I've settled on the current method.

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    if(locations.count > 0){

        let location = locations[0] as! CLLocation

        println(location.coordinate)

        currLocation = location.coordinate


        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            println(location)

            if error != nil {
                println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.lbutton.text="\(pm.locality)"
            }
            else {
                println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })



    } else {

        alert("Cannot fetch your location")

    }


}
```

Works like a charm without fail (however sometimes it takes a few minutes for the location to update but that's fair), however, I'm curious is it possible to have it pinpoint towns, rather than just the entire state? For example it would say Bushwick rather than just New York?

I know that there was recently (ish) a change to how reverse geocoding grabs it's data, but I figured I'd ask some people more versed in the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout all the properties you can get here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html

Comment: Thanks man, I was looking for the documentation but couldn't find this page. subLocation is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, for future reference you can search the class name in Xcode under Window > documentation & api reference, though I think it's a little cleaner on Apple's site.

Comment: Seems like it just sticks with boroughs, but I guess it can't go deeper. The weird part is that it can give me an exact street but not the neighborhood.

Comment: did you try the different admin areas?

Comment: Indeed. Didn't get the neighborhoods.

Comment: Just checked some code I had and for city I used locality.

Comment: I believe this issue here is the location it's trying to fetch. it seems like the borough, something fairly unique I suppose, supersedes that of a neighborhood for New York City.